# Formula for standard deviation differ from actual answer

Tags: statistics

Here is the question:

[image]

Source: OCR MEI A level Mathematics 2018 - Pure and Mechanics.

For question (i) I calculated the mean by taking the sum of the frequencies of the number of cars divided by the sum of the number of households.

$\mu = \frac{(0)(8)+(1)(22)+(2)(31)+(3)(27)+(4)(7)}{8+22+31+27+7}$
$= \frac{193}{95}$

Note this answer is correct, however for question (ii) my answer (which is incorrect) is as follows:
$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{((0)(8)-\mu)^2+((1)(22)-\mu)^2+((2)(31)-\mu)^2+((3)(27)-\mu)^2+((4)(7)-\mu)^2 }{8+22+31+27+7}} \approx 10.7 $

However, the actual value of $\sigma$ is approximately 1.07, where did I make my mistake?

EDIT:

The deviation of each term is not the difference between the frequency and the mean squared, but rather the product of the number of households and the deviation of the number of cars.

$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{8(0-\mu)^2+22(1-\mu)^2+31(2-\mu)^2+27(3-\mu)^2+7(4-\mu)^2 }{8+22+31+27+7}} \approx 1.07 $

Comment: For your middle term, e.g., you should have $31(2-\mu)^2$, and all five terms in the denominator should also be fixed analogously.

Comment: @JonathanZ What do you mean by "fixed analogusly"?

Comment: All five terms are wrong, and in the same way. I only showed you how the middle term should be. You need to make a similar fix to the other four terms.

Comment: One last thing @JonathanZ what is the reason/logic behind using the product of the number of households and the deviation between the number of cars and mu?

Comment: Hmmm, I think I'll have to write that up as a full answer. I won't get around to it until later today, so if anyone else feels like tackling that, feel free to go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, the standard deviation of the number of cars per household should not exceed the range of values that were reported.  Specifically, if only the values $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ were reported by all of the households surveyed, that means your standard deviation should not be more than $4$.

The way the data is presented in a table is just a convenient way to summarize the actual dataset, which might look more like this:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Household} & \text{Number of cars} \\
\hline
1 & 0 \\
2 & 4 \\
3 & 2 \\
4 & 1 \\
5 & 1 \\
6 & 2 \\
7 & 3 \\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{array}$$
So when you calculated the mean, what you actually did was take the number of households with $x$ cars and multiplied by $x$ to get the total number of cars among such households, for each $x \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$.  Then you divided by the total number of households to get the average.

But with the standard deviation, what you need to do is subtract the mean you obtained earlier from each of the values in the second column of the table, then take the square.  Add these all up and divide by the total number of households.  This gives the variance, from which you can calculate the standard deviation.  This is the second formula you provided in the edit to your question:

$$\sigma^2 = \frac{8(0 - \mu)^2 + 22(1 - \mu)^2 + 31(2 - \mu)^2 + 27(3-\mu)^2 + 7(4 - \mu)^2}{8 + 22 + 31 + 27 + 7},$$
where $$\mu = \frac{8(0) + 22(1) + 31(2) + 27(3) + 7(4)}{8 + 22 + 31 + 27 + 7}$$
was the sample mean you calculated earlier.

A probabilistic way to understand these computations is to construct a discrete probability distribution for the number of cars owned by a randomly selected household from this population.  Say this random variable is $X$.  Then the table tells us
$$\Pr[X = x] = \begin{cases}\frac{8}{95}, & x = 0 \\
\frac{22}{95}, & x = 1 \\
\frac{31}{95}, & x = 2 \\
\frac{27}{95}, & x = 3 \\
\frac{7}{95}, & x = 4.
\end{cases}$$
This is simply the number of households with $x$ cars divided by the total number of households from which we can randomly select, for each $x \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$.  Then the mean is $$\mu = \operatorname{E}[X] = \sum_{x=0}^4 x \Pr[X = x] = 0 \cdot \frac{8}{95} + 1 \cdot \frac{22}{95} + 2 \cdot \frac{31}{95} + 3 \cdot \frac{27}{95} + 4 \cdot \frac{7}{95},$$
and the second moment is
$$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = \sum_{x=0}^4 x^2 \Pr[X = x] = 0^2 \cdot \frac{8}{95} + 1^2 \cdot \frac{22}{95} + 2^2 \cdot \frac{31}{95} + 3^2 \cdot \frac{27}{95} + 4^2 \cdot \frac{7}{95}.$$
We use these to compute the variance through the formula
$$\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2.$$
The computation that we originally performed corresponds to the formula
$$\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[(X - \mu)^2] = \sum_{x=0}^4 (x - \mu)^2 \Pr[X = x].$$
I leave it to the reader to demonstrate that these yield the same result, as an exercise.